# Laravel Valet php-fpm already listening on valet sock

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

I've upgraded valet on my macbook (running catalina) and followed the laravel docs including re-running the `valet install` command and am seeing unexpected `502 Bad Gateway` errors. I was checking the logs and found

```
[27-Aug-2019 20:39:06] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/myuser/.config/valet/valet.sock
[27-Aug-2019 20:39:06] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/myuser/.config/valet/valet.sock
[27-Aug-2019 20:39:06] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[27-Aug-2019 20:39:06] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[27-Aug-2019 20:39:17] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/myuser/.config/valet/valet.sock
[27-Aug-2019 20:39:17] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/myuser/.config/valet/valet.sock
[27-Aug-2019 20:39:17] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[27-Aug-2019 20:39:17] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

It seems there's 3 `php-fpm` processes running though they all are the same php version (7.3).

Can anyone offer ideas of how to find where the other `php-fpm` process is being triggered from, and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After days of screwing around I found an answer on serverfault that suggested deleting the listening sock. So I ran `rm ~/.config/valet/valet.sock` and immediately the tailed php log showed

```
[08-Sep-2019 16:55:48] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 10316
[08-Sep-2019 16:55:48] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

So I guess that's all there was to it!

Comment: alternatively, you can run `rm ~/.valet/valet.sock`, this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
brew services list

dnsmasq   started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
nginx     started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php       started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist

brew services restart php

Stopping `php`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `php` (label: homebrew.mxcl.php)
==> Successfully started `php` (label: homebrew.mxcl.php)
```

php and php-fpm will work if you reload them

Answer (score 3):

Check whether there was an old/extra set of brew services installed:

```
ls -al /Library/LaunchDaemons/
```

and compare with:

```
ls -al ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

Remove duplicated `.plist` files, e.g.:

```
 homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
 homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
 homebrew.mxcl.php@7.4.plist
```

from one of the above folders.

Answer (score 2):

Run `valet install` that should solve your problem. After upgrading Valet version it is required to run this script.

Comment: I ran `valet install` after the composer global update, as specified in the laravel docs. Thanks!

Comment: Still having the same problem?

Comment: Although this looks like a clean solution, it doesn't work. The accepted answer is what worked for me.